# C# LINQ OrderBy strings with conditional integers

Tags: c#, string, linq, sorting

Please help me to deal with string sorting.

I have a List which contains the result of Oracle database select statement. In general it can look like this:

```
"9",
"10 k. 1 str. 1",
"10 k. 2 str. 1",
"11 k.1",
"12",
"12 k.1 str. 2"
```

but not so nicely ordered, of course.

I can sort it using LINQ-query such as:

```
var oLst = lst.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0])).ToList();
```

And it sorts this list, but only by first integers. What I want to do is some kind of "conditional ThenBy()" sorting based on the existence of `x.Split(' ')[2]` string element, but I can't figure out how to do it. What I want is to sort at first by "first" integers in strings, then, if they exist - by second ones, and then by third.

```
var oLst = lst.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0])).ThenBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ')[2])).ThenBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ').Last())).ToList();
```

works only with "full strings" which have all of integer values, but how can I manage the situation with non-existance of this `Split(' ')[]` elements in some strings of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a comparer:

```
public class NumberExtractorComparer : IComparer<MatchCollection>
{
    private static readonly Regex rx = new Regex("[0-9]+");

    public static readonly NumberExtractorComparer Comparer = new NumberExtractorComparer();

    // Returns a MatchCollection composed of all the groups of
    // digits
    public static MatchCollection Selector(string str)
    {
        return rx.Matches(str);
    }

    // Compares two matchcollections
    public int Compare(MatchCollection x, MatchCollection y)
    {
        int min = Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++)
        {
            // Using long to support bigger numbers
            long l1 = long.Parse(x[i].Value);
            long l2 = long.Parse(y[i].Value);

            int cmp = l1.CompareTo(l2);

            if (cmp != 0)
            {
                return cmp;
            }
        }

        return x.Count.CompareTo(y.Count);
    }
}
```

and then

```
var res = lst
    .OrderBy(
        NumberExtractorComparer.Selector, 
        NumberExtractorComparer.Comparer)
    .ToArray();
```

Note that I'm extracting the digits (the `NumberExtractorComparer.Selector`) BEFORE doing the comparison (the `NumberExtractorComparer.Comparer`). In this way, the digits will be extracted only once for each element of the collection (the digit extraction is probably quite slow compared to the comparison part)

Answer (score 0):

You can extarct number from string and sort by number value.

```
var oLst = lst.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(Regex.Replace(x, "[^0-9]", ""))).ToList();
```

Comment: I go test sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to double and then sort by that double. For example:

```
"9" => 9.0
"10 k. 1 str. 1" => 10.11
"10 k. 2 str. 1" => 10.21
"11 k.1" => 11.0
"12" => 12.0
"12 k.1 str. 2 => 12.2
```

The method that will do the trick is:

```
Parse(string str)
        {
            double res = 0;
            string[] p = str.Split(' ');

            double multuplier = 1.0;

            p.ToList().ForEach(f =>
            {
                int parsed;
                if(int.TryParse(f, out parsed))
                {
                    res += parsed * multuplier;
                    multuplier *= 0.1;
                }
            });

            return res;
        }
```

and then just use:

```
List<string> ordered = lst.OrderBy(Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from x in source
  let tokens = x.Split(' ')
  order by
    GentlyParse(tokens.FirstOrDefault()),
    GentlyParse(tokens.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()),
    GentlyParse(tokens.LastOrDefault())
  select x;

var results = query.ToList();
```

GentlyParse is a method you'll need to write which takes a string (or null) and returns either the int that can be parsed or null.